# JHipster User Authorization Implemetation

Tags: jhipster

I wanted to block some users for accessing some services in JHipster.
How can I authorize a particular user for accession a ReST web Service in JHipster?

Comment: What have you done so far? How does your authentication currently work? Your question is very vague.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on how to write questions. For starters: 1. Please format your code. 2. Add more code to your question to help us understand it better and for future readers to benefit from this question. 3. Look for other questions which might help you out already. 4. Format your text, and give us a minimum working example

Comment: Look at spring security doc about roles/authorities

Answer (score 3):

For blocking the access on the backend side, use the @Secured annotation on selected methods (rest entry points) in web/rest/*resource.java.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data-fields",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN})
public List<DataFieldDTO> getAllDataFields() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all DataFields");

    return dataFieldService.findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gaël Marziou says, I believe that what you are trying to do is to block it on frontend's part. If it´s the case a possible way to do it is managing the use of "has-authority". For example: has-authority="ROLE_ADMIN"

So what you should do is the opposite, create an authority which allows some users to have access to ReST web Service

Answer (score 0):

use has-authority and put your expected authority it will work 100% . tasted

write it on your html tag has-authority="ROLE_ADMIN" or your expected user

Answer (score 0):

On /config/SecurityConfiguration.java

You can change access of the api that you want like

```
   .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
   .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
   .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
   .antMatchers("/auth/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
```

Or you can use auth.inMemoryAuthentication()

for more information read link below:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions